# How to get main controller and action name in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .net core mvc web project and i'm trying to get action and controller name in the action. For example

```
 string actionName = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
 string controllerName = ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

those codes are giving me the value of controller and action but i wanna know which page did send that post.

For example: we have `HomeController` and `RequestQuote` action inside of that controller. If another page triggers that  `RequestQuote` action from different controller and action, i wanna get that controller and actions name. I hope i can be clear what i'm trying to meant it.

Comment: Hi @BerkGarip, If you just want to get controller action name which sends the request to another controller and only contains one such controller, just set the TempData or ViewData or Session in your action before you hit the another controller action.  If you want to globally get each controller action name which sends the request, I suggest you can add a global Action Filter and set the ViewData or TempData or Session for the controller action.

Comment: @Rena in normally, i'm doing it like you explained but i was trying to find a much simple way and your custom filter way is much sense. thank you for your respond!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

LoginController

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("RequestQuote", "Home");
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult RequestQuote()
    {
        string controllerName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("controller");
        string actionName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("action");
        return View();
    }
}
```

ActionFilter:

```
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string actionName = context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
        string controllerName = context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
        context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("controller", controllerName);
        context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("action", actionName);
    }
    public  void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        
    }      
}
```

Register the service in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(opt => {
    opt.Filters.Add(new CustomFilter());
});
```